# Java-based portal

Tags: java, content-management-system, portal

Can someone suggest a Java-based lightweight portal/CMS which is open source and free to install? Would be good if can be installed on Tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Liferay Community Edition.

http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/download/ce-vs-ee

However, it's not exactly lightweight.
But being open source, most of the bulk can be stripped out.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay as i know is a good lightweight open source portal